# I can't Install starUML StarUML-3.2.2 in lubunto 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I become my lab to Libuntu 18.04 Fosa and installing  some programs  like starUML. But  I have problems  when  writing in the terminal:

```
chmod a+x StarUML-3.2.2.AppImage
./StarUML-3.2.2.AppImage
```

Just open the APP but do not install.

Can someone help me please?

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

The AppImage is single executable file ([one app = one file](https://docs.appimage.org/introduction/concepts.html#one-app-one-file)). It does not install to the system by default.

But you can forcibly extract it and install as done in [ArchLinux AUR PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=staruml):

```
chmod +x StarUML-3.2.2.AppImage
./StarUML-3.2.2.AppImage --appimage-extract

sudo mkdir -p /opt/staruml /usr/local/share/applications /usr/local/bin/
find ./squashfs-root/* -path ./squashfs-root/usr -prune -o -prune -exec sudo cp -Rf {} /opt/staruml \;
sudo cp -Rf ./squashfs-root/usr/share/* /usr/local/share
sudo cp -fp  ./squashfs-root/staruml.desktop /usr/local/share/applications
sudo sed -i 's/AppRun/staruml/g' /usr/local/share/applications/staruml.desktop
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/staruml
sudo ln -fs /opt/staruml/staruml /usr/local/bin/staruml
sudo cp -Rf ./squashfs-root/usr/share/icons/* /usr/local/share/icons/
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/icons/
sudo ln -fs /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/staruml.png /opt/staruml/staruml.png
```

and then launch it from menus or using `staruml` command in the terminal.